# Laravel Validator Sometimes Conditional

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to test to find out if a date entered from a form is before or equal to a date from the database. This only needs to happen if another condition is true so I'm using the sometimes method off the validator.

Am I performing this logic correctly?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UserEditFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
    */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
     public function rules()
     {
        //dd($this->all());
        return [
            'hired_at' => 'required|date'
        ];
     }

    /**
     * Configure the validator instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
     * @return void
     */
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        if ($this->user->hasPosts()) {
            $validator->sometimes('hired_at', 'before_or_equal:'.$this->user->firstPostDate(), function($input) {
                //return true;
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you creating your validator?

Comment: With a form request class and adding the withValiddator method.

Comment: Can you add the code for the form request?

Comment: Edited for you.